# How do I remove the Enderdragon from the normal world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I accidentally spawned the Enderdragon in my normal world using the Single Player Command "spawn random".  Can I use any single player commands to remove this Enderdragon (or is there any other way)?  It is currently destroying all my hard earned creations.

Comment: Have you tried killing it?  It's really not hard at all - I did it my first time with a few wooden swords and no armor, without dying.  If you attack him when he gets near you, he doesn't hurt you, he just sort of pushes you *(which I'm assuming is a bug)*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Unfortunately I'm within a massive underwater city connected by corridors. The dragon is impossible to fight, it just destroys a module and swoops out of range!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/kill @e[type=ender_dragon]
```

This actually won't *kill* the dragon, but rather delete it outright (which means it will not drop experience).

Alternatively, you can do this instead:

```
/gamemode creative
/give @p netherite_sword{Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:255}]}
/effect give @p strength 600 255
```

… which switches you over to Creative, gives you a Sharpness 255 Netherite sword and a Strength buff. Fly up to the dragon and bonk it with the sword.

Comment: Thank you! /killall EnderDragon worked great. Now the rebuilding begins..